# how to create a list of folders for a file explorer app : android

Tags: android

What is the best way to create a thumbnail list of files for a file explorer app in android like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TjWWw.png). I understand how to create a list but dont know how to do that. Also, if I want to add a system so that user can flip between two view styles (one with list and one with those thumbnails), how should I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). If you know how to work with a `ListView` you can easily work with a `GridView` too. They are almost same, but `GridView` has multiple column support.

Comment: And if I have to switch between two views (list and grid), can I use the same adapter?

Comment: I think you can use the same adapter, but i am sure you want to use a different layout for the list and grid, therefore you would be making a different adapter. But you could use the same underlying DataSet for both the adapters.